# Is there a way to save a txt file under a new name after reading/writing the file?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to run a python program to open a template multiple times and while running through a loop, save multiple copies of the txt template under distinct file names.

An example problem is included below: The example template takes the following form:

```
Null Null
Null
This is the test
But there is still more text.
```

The code I've made to do a quick edit is as follows:

```
longStr = (r"C:\Users\jrwaller\Documents\Automated Eve\NewTest.txt")

import fileinput
for line in fileinput.FileInput(longStr,inplace=1):
    if "This" in line:
        line=line.replace(line,line+"added\n")
    print(line, end='')
```

The output of the code correctly adds the new line "added" to the text file:

```
Null Null
Null
This is the test
added
But there is still more text.
```

However, I want to save this new text as a new file name, say "New Test Edited" while keeping a copy of the old txt file available for further edits.

Comment: Why the `replace`? why not simply `line = line + "added\n"`?

Comment: @Tomerikoo Why the `line = line + "added\n"`? Why not simply `line += 'added\n'`? ;)

Comment: Tomerikoo's formatting actually helped me figure out another problem of how to add a line before a certain line (switch order). I haven't worked in Python much before this project so thanks for the help guys.

Comment: @Nordle true. Why not put it in your answer?

Comment: @Tomerikoo it's too much time tweaking things and not answering the question at hand. Code is nearly always improvable, but that's for codereview, OP just needed to know how to write to a new file on this occasion.

Comment: too much time? it is simply an obvious optimization, not to mention better python code (more readable), and the OP himself said this little change helped him. I don't see what's the big resentment for also improving the OP's code while addressing his original problem. If this is because I edited your answer I am deeply sorry, should have been a comment :)

Comment: @Tomerikoo In general, not just on one question. And no resentment at all! Edit all my answers if you feel they can be improved, I will accept if I agree :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example for you:

```
longStr = (r"C:\Users\jrwaller\Documents\Automated Eve\NewTest.txt")

with open(longStr) as old_file:
    with open(r"C:\Users\jrwaller\Documents\Automated Eve\NewTestEdited.txt", "w") as new_file:
        for line in old_file:
            if "This" in line:
                line=line.replace(line,line+"added\n")
            new_file.write(line)
```

A simple file read and write operation with a context managers to close up when you're finished.